# Lubuntu/Win 7 dual-boot: Attempting recovery of Windows 7 boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows, lubuntu, data-recovery, testdisk

I had both Windows 7 and Lubuntu 14.04 LTS in dual-boot. I wanted to reinstall Lubuntu since there were a couple of issues after having fiddled with multiple desktop environments. Popped in the bootable usb, chose "Reinstall Lubuntu 14.04". Woke up to realize that the option DID NOT do what it said to. Rather, it installed Lubuntu on the entire HDD and wiped the Windows boot. I'm now running Testdisk from a live image of Lubuntu and scanning for recoverable files. ATM it's still working.

Any advice?
This is what it shows at the moment.

> Analyse cylinder: 7000/60800: 11%
>   check_FAT: Unusual number of reserved sectors 8 (FAT), should be 1. MS
>   Data                 48335177   48367243      32067 [NO NAME]   MS
>   Data                 48335178   52512014    4176837 [NO NAME]
>   check_FAT: Unusual number of reserved sectors 6 (FAT), should be 1.
>   MS Data                 48335181   49074107     738927 [NO NAME]
>   check_FAT: Unusual number of reserved sectors 8 (FAT), should be 1.
>   MS Data                 48335182   48539981     204800 [NO NAME]   MS
>   Data                 48335183   50383182    2048000 [NO NAME]
>   check_FAT: Unusual number of reserved sectors 8 (FAT), should be 1.
>   MS Data                 48335678   48367744      32067 [NO NAME]   MS
>   Data                 48335679   52512515    4176837 [NO NAME]
>   check_FAT: Unusual number of reserved sectors 6 (FAT), should be 1.
>   MS Data                 48335682   49074608     738927 [NO NAME]
>   check_FAT: Unusual number of reserved sectors 8 (FAT), should be 1.
>   MS Data                 48335683   48540482     204800 [NO NAME]   MS
>   Data                 48335684   50383683    2048000 [.Win32.Comp]
>   check_FAT: Unusual number of reserved sectors 8 (FAT), should be 1.
>   MS Data                 50703470   50735536      32067 [NO NAME]   MS
>   Data                 50703471   54880307    4176837 [NO NAME]
>   check_FAT: Unusual number of reserved sectors 6 (FAT), should be 1.
>   MS Data                 50703474   51442400     738927 [NO NAME]
>   check_FAT: Unusual number of reserved sectors 8 (FAT), should be 1.
>   MS Data                 50703475   50908274     204800 [NO NAME]   MS
>   Data                 50703476   52751475    2048000 [NO NAME]
>   check_FAT: Unusual number of reserved sectors 8 (FAT), should be 1.
>   MS Data                 50703477   50735543      32067 [NO NAME]   MS
>   Data                 50703478   54880314    4176837 [NO NAME]
>   check_FAT: Unusual number of reserved sectors 6 (FAT), should be 1.
>   MS Data                 50703478   54880314    4176837 [NO NAME]

Comment: Did it remove the windows partition or simply Grub doesn't recognise Windows?

Comment: For the future: I always choose the "Something else" option and set things manually. It's worth the time learning about partitions to avoid similar problems.

Comment: When I try booting the computer from HDD, it doesn't find anything to boot. I forgot to mention that I aborted the Lubuntu reinstall. I realized after clicking the "Reinstall" option that it probably wasn't safe. Too late, I guess. I've tried Windows Repair but it said that the versions did not match. It's same disk.

Comment: Also tried BootRecover but it didn't find anything. Yes, I now understand that "Something else" is the way to go. It's the way I installed Lubuntu alongside Win7 to start with.

Comment: In fact, there was no HDD option at all in BIOS.

Comment: So probably, by aborting the install, you corrupted the hdd. With test disk try recoving the partition table not the files. If this doesn't help, you'll have to install Windows and then Lubuntu, I'm afraid.

Comment: In case **only** the partition table was overwritten it is a matter of seconds to recover it using testdisk. As soon as data were written as well you may only be able to recover untouched parts of your data but not your OSes. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu